# Anyone need a daily Ticker to CIK mapping?

Tags: market-data

Since I've seen several "Ticker (symbol) to CIK" mapping questions over the years, thought I'd put this out here.  I had a need to map this myself for another project.  I finally have a baseline that appears to work mapping daily NYSE, NASDAQ and BATS.  If you have interest in this daily mapping and would be willing to help me test this please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: If you're offering to share the data, then do so with the entire community.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I would be interested in validating, if you have historical data going back several years, as I'm trying to resolve tickers correctly over time...